# Super user limited to changing route table

Tags: routing, ip-routing, dynamic-routing

Background: I am trying to implement dynamic routing for a system.

Is it possible to create a super user that is restricted to changing the routing table? Something like a restricted `sudo` that can only run `route` or `ip route`?

I don't know exactly what would be the best way to do this, everything I think about is rather awkward. One idea I had was to run a service and simple write a file with the new table information and check whether that file changed.

The solutions I found were really strange, using virtual machines, which I would rather avoid.

Is there a good/safe or canonical way of doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: Why not restricted sudo?

Comment: I don't know, is this what I should use? I haven't done many things like this, how do I authenticate the new restricted superuser without having something like a password stored as plain text?

Comment: Maybe restricted sudo with passwordless authentication ( https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113754/allow-user1-to-su-user2-without-password/)

Comment: after reading the sudoers man page, the service file parser idea sounds like a much safer option.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use [bird](https://bird.network.cz/), which already implements all the kinds of dynamic routing protocols. It's the topnotch routing deamon at tis time (mid-spring 2021).  It runs from root; however, I really doubt you need to restrict it.

The approach you describing sounds more like reinventing the wheel. The triangle wheel.

Comment: Maybe this is the appropriate tool for the job, but to me it looks like a bazooka to swat a fly.